# How to run Mongo database db.currentOp(true) command using API

Tags: mongodb

To achieve the below mentioned shell command

> replicaset:PRIMARY> db.currentOp()

```
Am Using the Mongo Java API I can run the currentOp() command like this:   
MongoClient mongoClient = null;       
mongoClient = new MongoClient( "127.0.0.1", 27017);       
db = mongoClient.getDB("admin");       
db.command("currentOp");     

But I only get details of current operations. I need to get details of idle connections too.  
With reference with this
```

https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.0/reference/method/db.currentOp/#currentop-examples

Behavior

If you pass in true to db.currentOp(), the method returns information on all operations, including operations on idle connections and system operations.

db.currentOp(true) Passing in true is equivalent to passing in a query document of { '$all': true }.

If you pass a query document to db.currentOp(), the output returns information only for the current operations that match the query. You can query on the Output Fields. See Examples.

You can also specify { '$all': true } query document to return information on all in-progress operations, including operations on idle connections and system operations. If the query document includes '$all': true as well as other query conditions, only the '$all': true applies.

In Mongo command shell we have method like

> replicaset:PRIMARY> db.currentOp(true)

```
While using this command in JAVA API code      
db.command("currentOp(true)");           
I get an exception like this:     
>"ok" : 0.0 , "errmsg" : "no such command: 'currentOp(true)', bad cmd: '{ currentOp(true): true }'" , "code" : 59}
```

Please suggest an solution